# String, null и ""

Tags: java, строки, null

Мне нужно найти метод, который будет преобразовывать

```
String str = null
```

В

```
String str = ""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public String nullToEmptyString(String str) {
    return str == null ? "" : str;
}
```

Comment: Кстати, такой метод уже реализован в Guava: [com.google.common.base.Strings#nullToEmpty](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 6):

Для Java 8 можно ещё так

```
public String safeString(String str) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str).orElse("");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В Java 9 стиле

```
str = Objects.requireNonNullElse(str, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Всё очень просто:

```
public String nullToEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null ? "" : str;
}
```